# Regular expression for prefixed words

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find all word that are starting with bo or Bo or bO. How can I do this? This is my code:

```
     var name="Bob bOb ";
     var re=/Bo.*/;
     if (re.test(name))
     document.write("FOUND");
     else 
     document.write("NOT FOUND");
```

Comment: All words in the string, or a string starting with one of them? Please be specific when asking a question and add input and desired results

Answer (score 1):

you should make you're regex case insensitive like this `re=/Bo.*/i`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simply approach

```js
var name="Bob bOb ";
var results = name.split( /\s/ ).filter( function( item ){ return item.toLowerCase().indexOf( "bo" ) == 0 } );
console.log( results );
```